# Where is CIFaceFeature class object made available in iOS 5 face detection API

Tags: api, ios5, face-detection

According to my understanding of the Apple's documentation the 'CIFaceFeature' class' object is a container for the API calculated values of face features (namely hasLeftEyePosition, hasRightEyePosition, hasMouthPosition, leftEyePosition, rightEyePosition, mouthPosition), i.e. values for these properties are read only and will be set by some instance method(given the reference to an object of this class and a reference to an image as arguments). Unfortunately there is no mention of such function or any example :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011190

Comment: thanks dude... this example deals with all my doubts :-),, but you know Apple's examples are always a bit of work before you can get started !!